# Infinite loop when calling variable in data

Tags: javascript, async-await, vuejs3

I'm trying to dynamically populate a table with data using an API. I think I understand promised and awaits but I am not entirely sure if my approach is even remotely correct.

My table body code looks like the following:

```
<tbody>
    <div>{{ this.rows(table.id) }}</div>
    <div v-for="(item, idx) in this.TableRows" :key="idx">
        {{ item }}
    </div>
</tbody>
```

The code right now does not have any `tr` and `td` thats because I'm trying to confirm that the returned object is correct.

The functions I am using to get the data are as follows:

```
rows: async function(tableID) {
  await this.getRows(tableID).then(response => response.json()).then(items => {
    var temp = []
    items.forEach(item => {
      temp.push(JSON.parse(item.row_data))
    })

    this.TableRows = temp
    return temp
  })
},

getRows: async function(ID) {
  // call the custom_field_row_value api where the table id is current table id
  return fetch("http://endpoint/" + String(ID), {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With",
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
    }
  })
  // .then(response => response.json())   
},
```

In the rows function when I do `this.TableRows = temp` the api is being called in an infinite loop (the data that is being returned is correct though). I'm not sure why that is happening or how to fix it.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're not using `await` when you do `{{ this.rows(table.id) }}`. So it doesn't wait for the async operation to finish.

Comment: I don't think I can use an `await` there. As far as I understand, awaits can only be used in async functions

Comment: That's right. But since it's asynchronous, you can't use the result immediately after calling the function. You need to use `.then()`. I'm not sure how you handle async operations like this in Vue.

Comment: The template can't await anything.  `{{ this.rows(table.id) }}` initially displays the actual promise `[object Promise]`.  Later it returns a value, so the screen must rerender to display that value.  When the screen rerenders, it runs your template code again `this.rows(table.id)`, which returns a promise, which causes another rerender, and so on infinitely...  The solution is to not call this method in your template.  Have some separate data variable displayed in the template that gets updated by `rows` instead.  `rows` can be called in the created or mounted hook of your component.